# Is it ok to expand the answer to side related topics that might be useful?

Tags: discussion, answers

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817557/how-can-i-copy-visual-studio-2013-trial) the user asks how to obtain a Visual Studio 2013 trial ISO. I answered him how to exactly achieve that.

But given the context I thought it might be useful to give him more options, although it is not exactly what he asked. In this case how to get different versions of Visual Studio that might be better for him? **I am trying to be nice and helpful**

My questions are:

- Is acceptable/desired to do this in SO? Or should I answer strictely to the question?
- Should it better be a comment? (I put it in my answer because in a comment was very complicated)

Comment: The question seems off topic for SO - how is it not a resource request? Your answer basically consists of a link to the ISO, and thus becomes worthless once microsoft decides not to host it anymore, or change their link scheme. Your other options also just point to further downloads. So my answer to your first question would be that this type of question is not acceptable for SO.

Comment: You have a point. It had one close vote when I answered...